# Modifiable request headers with com.sun.net.httpserver.httpserver

Tags: java, http, servlets, server

I am creating a simple and lightweight reverse HTTP proxy and using [com.sun.net.httpserver.httpserver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) for it.

Once the proxy is done with its work it should add few headers in request headers and forward the request to actual service, however when i add anything in request headers i get UnsupportedOperationException because it is using [UnmodifiableHeaders](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/net/httpserver/UnmodifiableHeaders.html).

Can someone tell me how to configure com.sun.net.httpserver.httpserver to use modifiable headers?

Or is there any other better yet super lightweight HTTP server which supports this?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported operation
    at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.UnmodifiableHeaders.add(UnmodifiableHeaders.java:65)
    at com.example.SampleFilter.lambda$addValuesInRequestHeader$1(SampleFilter.java:80)
```

Comment: You should not use this package for this purpose. You can't write an HTTP proxy using an HTTP server, at least not one that will perform properly. You need to write at the TCP level and implement the necessary parts of HTTP yourself.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne So currently i am building a MVP and am not much concerned with performance. i have designed it in such a way that custom filters are in separate modules and can be reused in any other project, so replacing this package with something else won't be much issue for me in future. Apart from performance is there any other reason why you are suggesting me to implement it on TCP level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to add/edit headers but we can use httpExchange.setAttribute() and httpExchange.getAttribute() methods to pass additional information when hopping between filters.

For adding headers to the request that we want to forward to service, we create a new http request from the original one and include attributes in headers